# How to change the destination directory of 'yum install xxx'?

Tags: mysql, linux

I want to install mysql 5.6 server on my linux machine. I found the document in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html.
I guided me to install mysql via 'yum install'. But it seems that the mysql need a huge size about more than 1GB.

But my root directory is very small. How can I change the installation directory.

btw: I also tried other solution like **rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64.rpm**.But in this way, it depend on too much things that was hard to solve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to resize your disk , but you can try this

`yum --installroot=[custom_path] install [your_package]`

Think to add your custom path to your current path